# What code identifies users that are blocked in Azure MFA?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I can see on occasion users are blocked under 'Multi-Factor Authentication | Block/unblock users'. I would like to identify these users using Powershell. I'm thinking perhaps status code from Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs could help, but I dont know which code would reference the block. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the MFA status of the user to CSV using powershell . Kindly go through the [document](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Export-Office-365-Users-81747c73?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-UM4v.9vVeaqnRdN5vJgRkQ&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-UM4v.9vVeaqnRdN5vJgRkQ&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2000142_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=%28ir__9s0bqllgq0kftx3qkk0sohzz0e2xnegd93uf2e2x00%29%287593%29%281243925%29%28je6NUbpObpQ-UM4v.9vVeaqnRdN5vJgRkQ%29%28%29&irclickid=_9s0bqllgq0kftx3qkk0sohzz0e2xnegd93uf2e2x00) to get more details.

Comment: I can obtain MFA status with MSOL commands. I was really wondering if any correlation exists between the AzureADAuditSignInLog error codes and the MFA block list.

Comment: The error codes generally explains what applications signed in to , which sign In fails and why.